# getDeclaredField and Annotation

Tags: spring, reflection, annotations, spring-validator

I am using springframework validator to validate my applications. Currently I am passing my fieldname as a hardcoded string to the validator. This has caused a lot of issue, where if a fieldname in the model changes the validations would fail.

I have looked into reflection to get the filename from the model using getDeclaredField. This method however returns a list of files for that class and if I need to get a specific field I will have to pass the right index. Eg. `fields[8].getName()`. So if the positioning of the fields changes I will have an issue.

I am wondering if there is any other simpler way I can pass a specific fieldname to the rejectValue ? would a custom annotation work? Like

`@firstName
private String           firstName;`

then use getDeclaredAnnotations to get my fieldname?

Here is how I am doing it now.

```
private String           firstName;
private String            lastName;

errors.rejectValue("lastName ", ValidationConstants.INVALID_NULL_OR_BLANK_CODE);
```

If I am using reflection

```
errors.rejectValue(fields[2].getName(), ValidationConstants.INVALID_NULL_OR_BLANK_CODE);
```

Comment: Have a look at JSR 303 Bean Validation, it is also supported by Spring, http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/12/spring-bean-validation-example-with-jsr-303-annotations/

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I have look at bean validation. unfortunately, to use this we will need to re-do our validation for all of our apps. I am trying to find a solution to replace the hard-coded string. I am sure its possible :)